# get 400 bad request after requesting GET in python

Tags: python, get, request, zendesk

Id like to convert this curl command to python script

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN" https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats
```

I wrote the python script below but I get `<Response [400]>`and doesn't work.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats"
access_token = "MYTOKEN"

response = requests.post(url,
      headers={"Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
               "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token)})
print(response)
```

Any advice will be appreciated.thanks.

Comment: Try flipping the order of the headers and removing `;charset=UTF-8`

Comment: thanks for the comment but nothing has changed even after doing that...

Comment: Check the token, if it is expired and how long it takes to expire.

Comment: Might be a good idea to print out the actual body of the response. It could contain a helpful error message.

Comment: I created a new token and replace it but still get 400...

Comment: I get ```{"error":"SchemaError","description":"Unable to decode json payload"}``` FYI

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you are sending a POST request without any data, only the headers and url.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `requests.get` instead of `requests.post`, since what you want is a GET request:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.zopim.com/api/v2/chats"
access_token = "MYTOKEN"

response = requests.get(url,
      headers={"Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",
               "Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(access_token)})
print(response)
```